# Android Avd running with errors

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I have installed Android 4.3 AVD bundle on Ubuntu 12.4 LTS. When I start AVD it shows too many errors.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_3_7_FWVGA_slider'
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

How to fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

be sure that a version of libGL is installed. Try the following command:

`locate libGL`

You will properbly get a bunch of libGL's that hanging around on your system ... 
Pick one of them and copy the path. Now type:

`ln -s <path_to_your_desired_libGL.so.1> /lib/libGL.so`